# I am trying to get the rootViewController from the AppDelegate using the didFinishLoadingWithOptions method, but I can't access the window

Tags: ios, ios13

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let navController = window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
        let personController = navController.controllers[0] as? PeopleTableViewController{
        print("something")
    }
    return true
}
```

But it is giving me an error, it is not recognizing the window property of the AppDelegate, did they change with IOS 13 because it works in my IOS 12 project

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
     let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
     container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
         if let error = error {
             fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)")
         }
     }
     return container
 }()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
        let personController = navController.viewControllers[0] as? PeopleTableViewController{
        personController.persistentContainer = persistentContainer
        print("Nailed it ")
    } else {
        print("Sorry")
    }
    return true
}

// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    persistentContainer.saveContextIfNeeded()
}
```

}

This is how my AppDelegate class looks

Comment: Hi, inside the AppDelegate, do you have the variable "var window: UIWindow?" above the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function?

Comment: Not that I created, isn't it automatic and IOS create ?

Comment: If you create a project in Xcode 11, the window variable won't be there by default because of Xcode 11 defaults to the new Swift UI project setup.

Comment: Oh, Ok. so if I add that var window : UIWindow? do I initialize it or is the system gonna do that for me. I just start using It

Comment: It should work by just adding it, and also make sure that you have the "Main.storyboard" selected under the "Main Interface" in the project settings.

Comment: I did it, unfortunately its jumping over the if statement, not instantiating the window property

Comment: Can you please share more code so I can what do you refer to?

Comment: Is PeopleTableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes, the error is the first optional checking window?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: if window == nil {

Comment: if window == nil { print("It is nil") }       result.    it is nil

Comment: You don't need to check for window nil because you are already safely unwrapping it in the line - if let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
            let personController = navController.viewControllers[0] as? PeopleTableViewController {

Comment: I know. but it is the same thing. it is making the window property nil because I made it an optional and didn't assign a value \

Comment: You don't need to assign it with a value, the system should do it for you.

Comment: it should. but it is not doing

Comment: Hi, I apologize. We do need to set the window variable, I am not sure if this is still relevant but inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions we need to add "self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)".

Comment: I find way around thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way around. instead of putting your code in didFinsishLoadingWithOptions method, getting the UIview comptroller's persistentContainer variable and then passing the persistentContainer in AppDelegate. you can just add this to the top of the view Controller.

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.context
```

if you want the appDelegate you can access like this

```
let AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

This works both IOS12 and IOS13 so, you don't have to change your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you set App's initialView Controller/rootViewController inside Scene Delegate class (this class handles Application Lifecycle Methods which were earlier handled by AppDelegate).

import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {


    let initialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "DatePicker")  as! DatePicker

    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = tabBarCnt
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
    // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
    // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
    // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
}

func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
    // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
}

func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
    // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
    // to restore the scene back to its current state.

    print("App entered Background")
}
```

}

Comment: This true and correct, I was looking for a way to pass the persistentContainer in AppDelegate to what ever view controller I wanted. I could put the persistentContainer in SceneDelegate put I wanna access it multiple Scenes, so the appropriate place is AppDelegate. I found a way and posted